# What level of hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to use in development mode

Tags: hibernate, hbm2ddl

my case is as follows:

1. I make changes in already existing tables.
2. I add new tables.
3. In the import script for hibernate (import.sql) sometimes i make changes in old queries and sometimes i add new queries.
4. In Production it should be set to none, and use an sql script instead, right ?

please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It should be

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

Also the other important properties should be set at a development env only,

```
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
```

To track the hibernate queries generated.